Weird behavior, all vertices merge into one point when resizing
I am a beginner and I have a strange behavior with Blender 4.2.1 LTS.  
For example (see GIF), I loop select some edges, then press "S" to resize and "X" for the X axis, then "Left click";
Each time, everything merges on an unwanted vertex.
I tried to change many settings, like transform orientations (global, local, etc...).
I also applied Object > All Transforms.
Or reset the object origin.
Nothing solved my problem.
Any idea how to solve this strange behavior please?
Thanks.

You have the "auto merge" turned on, and your "threshold" is too big (these points are too near each other compared to the threshold)

